# Change the layout of ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am curious if it is possible to change the layout of the ggplot legend without having to rewrite the build_legend function?

For example:

I want a 2 * 2 layout

a b 
c d

rather than the normal 1 * 4 or 4 * 1 layout.

a
b
c
d

or

a 
 b 
 c 
 d

Many Thanks,

MK

Comment: Please don't cross post - it wastes people's time answering questions that might have already been answered elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you Hadley, I thought that was only restricted between mailing lists.

Comment: I was going to answer my own question(with Kohske's solution and credits to him) so other people who are not on the mailing list can see it, but there was time restriction on when I could answer my question so I couldn't post it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't actually think this is possible with ggplot2, you really only have two options - horizontal or vertical. If you want to create something fancier, you'd have to do it yourself by creating a subplot with the same colour scheme, resizing and overlaying it onto your plot (I would envision something like a small facet_grid() placed wherever it may be appropriate).

```
... + opts(legend.direction="horizontal")
... + opts(legend.direction="vertical")
```

Answer (score 3):

Kohske has posted the solution to the problem, although it will not be available until the next version of ggplot.

```
qplot(1:4, 1:4, colour = letters[1:4]) + guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 2, byrow = T))
```

Comment: Link to Kohske's response to your same question on the ggplot2 list: http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/msg/4a8b39ff690eaf48

Comment: Thanks competent_tech and Brian for the edit and the links. I'll do my best to keep my codes and format to the standard.  Cheers,